# Python: sqlite OR statement

Tags: python, sql, linux, sqlite, ubuntu

Is there an OR sqlite statement? I've been trying to google it, but google seems to be filtering out the *OR*.

For example if I wanted to find someone in this table (people)

```
people:
+--fname--+--lname--+--has_squirrel--+
|Eric     |Schmidt  |0               |
+---------+---------+----------------+
|Elvis    |Presley  |1               |
+---------+---------+----------------+
|Richard  |Stallman |0               |
+---------+---------+----------------+
```

with a first name of either Elvis or Richard, what would my query be?

I've tried things like `select * from people where fname=('Elvis' or 'Richard')`, but that always returns *Eric Schmidt* (the exact opposite rows of what I want)!

I've also tried `select * from people where fname='Elvis' or 'Richard'` but that returns *all* the rows in the table!

I'm using the Python 2.6 sqlite3 module on Ubuntu 10.10. Can someone give me a quick explanation of the sqlite OR statment or tell me if it doesn't exist? I've tried to RTFM and I couldn't find anything (searching for *OR* on the sqlite website spits out a bunch of errors!).

Thanks!

Comment: You have a problem with your condition! See my answer below, I explained a bit.

Comment: if you google 'sql +or' it will listen to you better.

Comment: Thanks nate! I'll remember that!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It would be one of those :

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE fname IN ('Elvis', 'Richard');
SELECT * FROM people WHERE fname = 'Elvis' OR fname = 'Richard';
```

I'm surprised your first query even works, and in your second, `or 'Richard'` basically means `or 1=1`, which is always true, for every row in your table.

Your computer doesn't think like you do. Even if `fname = 'Elvis' or 'Richard'` seems obvious to you, the RDBMS doesn't know what you mean and reads "if fname is equal to 'Elvis' or... true". It evalutes the string to a boolean, and I assume since it's not empty, it's evaluated to true. And proceeds to select every row from your table, as I said earlier.

Comment: I'm a fan of `IN` because it's easily extensible, the parentheses distinguish the list of alternatives, and decent text editors will let you bounce back and forth between them. As a bonus, it looks a lot like a list comprehension: `[row for row in people if row.fname in ('Elvis', 'Richard')]`

Comment: Aha! `IN` is what I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"SQLite logical operators" was my query, and found you this: http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitetutorial/expressions/

As to your actual results, you're comparing cows with donkeys :D. When you say:

```
select * from people where fname='Elvis' or 'Richard'
```

You're saying:

> Give me all the rows from people that
>   satisfy the following: it's true that
>   fname equals Elvis, or it's true that
>   Richard.

You're getting all the rows because Richard is considered true, being a non-empty string.

What you should do is:

```
select * from people where fname='Elvis' or fname='Richard'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

just a quick one, have you tried `select * from people where fname='Elvis' or fname='Richard'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from people where fname = 'Elvis' or  fname = 'Richard'
```

Answer (score 0):

OR is a logical statement that returns true or false.

So ("Elvis" or "Richard") returns probably false. 
And your actual SQL is really " fname = False ". most databases would throw an error but because sqlite internally follows TCL's "everything is a string" philosophy it is a valid statement.

What you need is simply:

```
select * from people where fname='Elvis' or fname =  'Richard'
```