# OR statement in jquery for android html5 database

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

Below is my code from which I can search from database, but I want it to search with OR statement rather than AND statement.

```
var sea=$("#search").val();
var sear=$.trim(sea);
var test = sear.split(" ");
var arrDistinct = new Array(); 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(test).each(function(index, item) { 
        if ($.inArray(item, arrDistinct) == -1) 
        arrDistinct.push(item); 
    }); //end each
    $(arrDistinct).each(function(index, item) { 

        //database
        var db = openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Inventory", 200000);
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO WHERE (D_Indications LIKE ?);", ["%"+item+"%"],

                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    $('#output2').append('<tr><td>'+ results.rows.item(i).Cat_name +'</td><td>'+ results.rows.item(i).Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ results.rows.item(i).G_Name +'</td><td>'+ results.rows.item(i).B_Name +'</td><td>'+ results.rows.item(i).D_Indications +'</td></tr>').trigger('create');

                }//end for

                });//end function


            });//end db transaction

        }); //end each function

});//document ready
```

When A user enters "Hello World" I want it to search database with "%Hello%" OR "%World%"
How can I do that with jquery?

Comment: I can't see a question mark. Is there a question?

Comment: Essentially, you want `"%" + item + "%"` to evaluate to `"%Hello% OR %World%"`? I guess `test.join("% OR %")` could do the job, but I'm not sure what `test` is.

Comment: item is the array of words typed in the search box.

Answer (score 0):

See this post if you want to know sqlite OR statement [Python: sqlite OR statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221956/python-sqlite-or-statement)

Comment: I am using html5 sqlite database so the code you have provided wont work.

Comment: Question was about OR syntax of sqlite, it should not matter whether you use html5 sqlite or sqlite with some other device/setup? If you have problems with basic syntax review this tutorial content: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html